# Postpone logging page_view

Tags: google-analytics-4

We're workinig with a site where pages fetch their content via Ajax, after the HTML document has loaded. As a consequence, where GA4 fires its page_view the page title tag (which I think is where the page_title parameter gets its value?) has not been populated, and the value passed to GA isn't useful.

Is there a standard (or obvious) way of fixing this, I wondered if the page_view event could be put off until the content is loaded (at which point the title tag would contain the correct content), for example?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a visible object that appears after the Ajax but not before, then you could fire a custom `page_view` event when that element is visible.

There probably isn't an easy way to do that with the main config tag that registers the out of the box `page_view` event. Or at least one that I would mess with.

Comment: No, this is the conclusion I've reached too. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the following answer, as it provides several scenarios and ways to make what you want work:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199037/how-do-i-get-google-analytics-to-track-pages-called-by-ajax

Comment: None of that's applicable is it, it's the previous version of GA (Universal Analytics)?